# Integer to byte array arduino BLE

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I want to convert an interger to bytes array and send it via BLE using the writeValue() function:

```
            int x;
            String strx; 
            x=accel.x();
            strx=String(x);
            byte bytes[4];
            strx.getBytes(bytes,2)
            Serial.print(sizeof(bytes));
            accelxCharacteristic.writeValue(bytes,4);
```

but I am having this error:

no matching function for call to 'BLEIntCharacteristic::writeValue(byte [4], int)

Comment: The message is clear: there is no method `writeValue` for objects of class `BLEIntCharacteristic`. What is your specific question?

Comment: In the documentation there is a function "writeValue" that sends a bytes array I found out that it depends from the characteristic there are these options:

Comment: BLECharacteristic(uuid, properties, value, valueSize)
BLECharacteristic(uuid, properties, stringValue)

BLEBoolCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEBooleanCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLECharCharacteristic(uuid, properties)....

Comment: I was declaring it as BLEIntCharacteristic now I changed it to BLECharacteristic so it can send a bytes array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to be careful on how I declare the characteristic there are these options in the documentation:

```
BLECharacteristic(uuid, properties, value, valueSize)
BLECharacteristic(uuid, properties, stringValue)

BLEBoolCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEBooleanCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLECharCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEUnsignedCharCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEByteCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEShortCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEUnsignedShortCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEWordCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEIntCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEUnsignedIntCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLELongCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEUnsignedLongCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEFloatCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
BLEDoubleCharacteristic(uuid, properties)
```

Make sure if you are sending a buffer to use:

```
 BLECharacteristic(uuid, properties, value, valueSize)
```